# Is it possible to define a constant using a PHP stdClass object?

Tags: php, stdclass

The [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) class constants page doesn't mention anything about this, nor have I found other questions that have the answer.

I was surprised I couldn't find the answer to this, maybe I didn't look well enough, but is it possible to define a constant for a stdClass object like:

```
<?php
$foo = new stdClass();

#something magic here like:
const $foo->pi = 3.14;

#and then get access like:
echo $foo::pi;
```

If it isn't possible, why is it not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not make a class with constant variables? Usually they should be static as objects define a state of class having variable properties and constants are more class based.

Comment: I didn't know you could assign constant variables to a stdClass instance, the only reason I wanted this to work was that I group variables using stdClass instead of arrays, and being able to use constants is sometimes useful. Really I just wanted to know if it's possible, but it looks like it can't be done.

Comment: It would be interesting to understand what this "grouping" entails, and why you wouldn't just use a normal class, or perhaps, as I suggested in my answer, an anonymous class.  An anonymous class that implements an interface might be a workaround for you, but I'd also then wonder why not use a class you designed in advance.

Comment: I would say I'm not an expert in PHP, and I haven't come across anonymous classes until now, I might have been using stdClass incorrectly, and I should probably investigate alternative ways of creating the objects I need. Answering your question from the answer below @gview this was more of an academic question than something else, although it is helpful to know the limitations of using stdClass for what I will be doing.

Comment: Totally fair question.  If you came from javascript, PHP is more of a traditional OOP language (not prototype based) although it does allow you to add properties to an object on the fly which might lead one to believe it is more like javascript than it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.  And the reason is simple.  Constants are static idempotent values created at compile time.

They are not variables.

Your syntax actually attempts to add a property/variable to an object and then utilize that as a constant, which is why you get a syntax error when you try to access it of `Undefined class constant 'stdClass::pi'`

If there is some reason you are attempting to do this, beyond the academic, you might want to create a new question that explains what you want and why.  There are some interesting features of PHP (anonymous classes for example) that might allow you some sort of workaround, although the obvious traditional solution is just to define a base class and utilize inheritance to inherit things.

Interfaces can also define constants, so you can share constants with various classes by defining an interface with the constants you want defined and have the class implement the interface.